# Closing a WebSocket properly

Tags: angularjs, websocket

When I close the `websocket(ws.$close())` in my AngularJS application it takes about 40 seconds until it actually closes and I receive the `onclose` event.  am using the [ng-websocket library](https://github.com/wilk/ng-websocket). Simple test code for example:

```
angular.module("mainModule").controller("mainController", function ($scope, $http, $websocket, $rootScope) {
    $scope.dataImage = "#";
    $scope.webSocket = null;

    $scope.testWebSocket = function () {
        $scope.webSocket = $websocket.$new({
            url: 'ws://someurl',
            reconnect: true
        });

        $scope.webSocket.$on('$message', $scope.imageArrived);
    }

    $scope.closeWebSocket = function () {
        $scope.webSocket.$un('$message');
        $scope.webSocket.$close();
        $scope.dataImage = "#";
    }

    $scope.imageArrived = function (imageMessage) {
        console.log("image arrived");
        $scope.dataImage = "data:image/gif;base64," + imageMessage.Data;
        $rootScope.$apply();
    }
});
```

I created a WPF test application also using websockets and there I receive the `onclose` event immediately. Is there a way to speed up closing of the websocket?

Comment: To correctly close a Websocket both the client and the server must send a close frame. is your WPF implementation sending a close frame too?